# How to enable autolayout in storyboard Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to enable autolayout by clicking on 'Use Auto Layout' on following option in storyboard[image]

but after a while, it just appears a lock on screen indicating it is not possible, and checkbox is never selected

[image]

how to enable it properly?

Answer (score 3):

Enable "Use Trait Variations" too, It will enable "Auto Layout" automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Use Auto layout" from 1 option of storyboard as shown in image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The lock appears when you try to change any property because the viewcontroller that is selected is locked. To enable editing select the viewcontroller from storyboard and goto `Identity Inspector` tab from Inspectors pane and set the Lock option to `Inherited(Nothing)` or `Nothing`

Attached is the screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I knew finally how!!!
I had to select on Project Navigation my .storyboard file and then go to:

> Editor -> Localization Locking -> Reset Locking Controls

and now I can select Autolayout